# Is there such a thing as a visual development environment for C++?

Tags: ide, visual-programming

By "visual development environment", I do not mean Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm looking for a node-based IDE in which programs are constructed graphically and converted to plain text at compile time. The content of functions would still have to be typed out, of course, but everything else would be visual. Sort of like a flow chart that you type your code into directly.

I feel like this should exist but I can't seem to find anything like it.

Comment: This has been the goal of the industry for years, the "lego era".

Comment: If there is such a thing, then all of us real programmers would be out of business. :)

Comment: Isn't that what C++ Builder tried to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools which allow you to design your software using [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). Some of these tools include code generation capability (although as you say, you may have to enter code to implement decision points, etc).

One example is [IBM Rational Rose](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ratirosefami). An open source example is [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 0):

DRAKON Editor
http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/
It it supports visual programming in C++, also support QT. It also supports many other programming languages.
Why to use DRAKON than other diagramming systems?

- No line intersections. You will never find in DRAKON diagram two or
  more lines intersecting each other! Not seen in other diagramming
  systems!
- Silhouette structure. It allows to break one diagram in to several
  logical parts. Not seen in other diagramming systems!
- No slanting or curved lines. Only straight lines with right angles.
- Icons are placed only on vertical lines.
- Branching is done in a simple, visible and consistent way.
- Each diagram has one entry and one exit.

More about DRAKON here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON